# Rails .where using AND / OR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model `Tasks` that has the fields `completed:boolean` and `completed_date:datetime`.

If a task is completed it will have the date when it was marked as completed, or else `completed_date` would be false.

I'm trying to write an query that looks for all tasks where `completed = false` and `completed_date less than 2 days ago OR`completed = true`and`completed_date = nil`

Something like this isn't working `current_user.account.tasks.where("(completed = ? AND completed_date = ?) OR (completed = ? AND completed_date > ?)", false, nil, true, Time.now - 2.days)` in my controller.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get a compiler error? Runtime error? Incorrect results? What kind of type is Tasks?

Comment: Just returned the wrong results. Question has been answered, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the same thing like

```
current_user.account.tasks.where("completed_date is NULL OR completed_date > ?", 2.days.ago)
```

and shouldn't have any error (unless there's something wrong with your associations)

You shouldn't need `completed_date` and `completed`. You can use just `completed_date` for both checks (`completed_date` not `null` means `completed` is `true`)